# Missing extras folder in sdk manager in android studios

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

There is no extras folder in sdk manager in my android studios.Why is it so?

[image: This is a screenshot of my sdk manager.]

Comment: See below **Launch Standalone SDK Manager** it will open old SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the launch standalone sdk manager link at the bottom of the sdk manger as you can see in the screen shot.

Comment: **Launch Standalone SDK Manager** is removed too.