# Android Studio - Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run an Android Studio project, but when I do, it fails:

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy) suggests that I should reinstall the android support repository, and [this guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) suggests that I should look in the Extras folder in the SDK Manager window, but there is no such folder:

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407917/missing-extras-folder-in-sdk-manager-in-android-studios) says I should use the Launch Standalone SDK Manager button, but that also does not exist for me.

I'd appreciate help, thank you.

Comment: are you missing the support libraries as dependency in your project?

Comment: how you fix this issue

Comment: I don't recall, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Think you are missing the support libraries you need. They are not part of android sdk.

build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

just a copy paste, try out which one you really need at the end. Also the versions should be as your exception tells you